# Custom AVAudioUnit with AVAudioEngine crashes on set provider block

Tags: core-audio, avaudioengine

I have the follow code block that *should* create an AVAudioNode that produces a sine wave, however it crashes on the line marked with a -[AUAudioUnitV2Bridge setOutputProvider:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

```
// TEST  
AudioComponentDescription mixerDesc;  
mixerDesc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Generator;  
mixerDesc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_ScheduledSoundPlayer;  
mixerDesc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;  
mixerDesc.componentFlags = 0;  
mixerDesc.componentFlagsMask = 0;  

[AVAudioUnit instantiateWithComponentDescription:mixerDesc options:kAudioComponentInstantiation_LoadInProcess completionHandler:^(__kindof AVAudioUnit * _Nullable audioUnit, NSError * _Nullable error) {  
    NSLog(@"here");  

    // Crashes here  
    audioUnit.AUAudioUnit.outputProvider = ^AUAudioUnitStatus(AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *actionFlags, const AudioTimeStamp *timestamp, AUAudioFrameCount frameCount, NSInteger inputBusNumber, AudioBufferList *inputData)  
    {  
        const double amplitude = 0.2;  
        static double theta = 0.0;  
        double theta_increment = 2.0 * M_PI * 880.0 / 44100.0;  
        const int channel = 0;  
        Float32 *buffer = (Float32 *)inputData->mBuffers[channel].mData;  

        memset(inputData->mBuffers[channel].mData, 0, inputData->mBuffers[channel].mDataByteSize);  
        memset(inputData->mBuffers[1].mData, 0, inputData->mBuffers[1].mDataByteSize);  

        // Generate the samples  
        for (UInt32 frame = 0; frame < inputBusNumber; frame++)  
        {  
            buffer[frame] = sin(theta) * amplitude;  

            theta += theta_increment;  
            if (theta >= 2.0 * M_PI)  
            {  
                theta -= 2.0 * M_PI;  
            }  
        }  

        return noErr;  
    };  

}];
```

**UPDATE**

It feels like something like this would be the right approach, but alas, status throws errors, callback never called.:

```
    AVAudioUnitGenerator *unit = [[AVAudioUnitGenerator alloc] init];

// TEST
AudioComponentDescription desc;
desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Generator;
desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_ScheduledSoundPlayer;
desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
desc.componentFlags = 0;
desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;

[AVAudioUnit instantiateWithComponentDescription:desc options:kAudioComponentInstantiation_LoadInProcess completionHandler:^(__kindof AVAudioUnit * _Nullable audioUnit, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"here");

    self.audioNode = audioUnit;

    OSStatus status;
     AudioUnit *unit = audioUnit.audioUnit;

    UInt32 numBuses = 1;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(unit, kAudioUnitProperty_ElementCount, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &numBuses, sizeof(UInt32));
    NSLog(@"status: %d", status);


    AURenderCallbackStruct rcbs;
    rcbs.inputProc = callback2;
    rcbs.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void * _Nullable)(self);


    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(unit, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &rcbs, sizeof(rcbs));
    NSLog(@"status: %d", status);

}];
```

Comment: Is an error sent to your completion handler? You should have that error check.

Comment: The error is returning nil

Comment: @Taylor here's a project that shows the crash: https://bitbucket.org/rfistman/proceduralavaudiounit

Comment: @RhythmicFistman - Thank you for posting that sample!

Comment: Thanks for this post, I had been pulling my hair out because I kept trying to use AVAudioUnit.audioUnit instead of AVAudioUnit.AUAudioUnit to access the underlying AUAudioUnit. How in God's name is anyone supposed to know this distinction?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what the error message says.  After instantiating your requested type of audioUnit and making sure the AUAudioUnit isn't nil, this code makes it explicit:

```
if (![audioUnit.AUAudioUnit respondsToSelector:@selector(outputProvider)]) {
        NSLog(@"selector method not found in this instance of an AUAudioUnit");
}
```

The header file does not claim that this method is absolutely required to be implemented in all audio units.

Added later:  If you just want to have your code synthesize samples for an AVAudioUnit, and don't care about the specific API or code structure, then: 
 Get the AudioUnit property of your AVAudioUnit instance; create an AURenderCallback function; fill in an AURenderCallbackStruct with this C function; then do an AudioUnitSetProperty for kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback on the AudioUnit.  This seems to not crash even if no outputProvider method is available.

Comment: That's true, but `AUAudioUnitV2Bridge`'s super class, `AUAudioUnit`, declares that property, so it being unimplemented is just weird. However, a comment in the header says that these methods are only "for audio units which can do input/output" - so maybe the OP's question should be "how can I create an output `AUAudioUnit`?". I'm interested because I've always wondered how you do procedural output/replace remote io audio units with `AVFoundation`.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman - All I want to do is simply generate a sine wave, I can do it with a weird tap on a file player, but it's just too odd. Surely this must be possible.

Comment: @hotpaw2 - Can you point me in the direction of any code for that? I really just want to use AVAudioEngine at a high level as possible.

Comment: I'd like to know how to do it too - I have a feeling that you have to create a custom audio unit (AV or AU? Not sure)

Comment: UPDATE: sorry, hadn't read @hotpaw2's edit.  If you're in a rush, just use a core audio unit - they certainly do support procedural sample generation. It might even be possible to wrap _that_ audio unit in an `AVAudioUnit` if you absolutely must use `AVAudioEngine`.

Comment: Setting the `kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback` property of the `AVAudioUnit`'s audio unit is a really good idea!

Comment: Like this?

status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit.audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &rcbs, sizeof(rcbs));

Comment: Example using kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433325/how-do-i-connect-a-mixer-with-an-augraph

Comment: @hotpaw2, the example you showed uses AUGraph, which Apple has deprecated. Have you been able, at all to get the above to work? You say the problem (and solution?) is clear, but its clear as mud to me.

Comment: Custom AVAudioUnit synthesis example (needs updating): https://github.com/hotpaw2/auv3test5